# Deploy new version to google app engine not work

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, jhipster

I m a new user in the google cloud platform,
I followed the jhipster tutorial to deploy the jhipster web application to Google App Engine.
(https://www.jhipster.tech/gcp/)
I can deploy the original version of jhipser to GCP app engine, but when I deploy again it was not updated to the new version even my local was updated.

Does anyone know how to deploy new version to Google app engine??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about jhipster, but if it is a classical java web application on app engine, as stated in the link you provided, you just need to re-deploy again:

```
./mvnw package appengine:deploy -DskipTests -Pgae,prod-gae
```

if you want to deploy as a new version, you should check what is the version parameter provided. You can find that in app.yaml, application-web.xml or pom.xml file depending on how the application is built.

If who built the application decided to automatically increment the version each deploy, you should have already everything set, but in App Engine > Version page in GCP you should migrate the traffic to your latest version.

Comment: Thank you for your help, How can I set the application using default URL? If I set version the URL will become (https://2-dot-{project_name}.appspot.com/).

Comment: you have to migrate traffic for that, in gcp > App Engine > versions > select version + press migrate traffic.

Comment: Thanks Pievis, I tried to migrate traffic to the new version, but the website always displays the old version and doesn't show any error message. Do I need to stop the service or something?

Comment: mm no that should be it, maybe try to invalidate the cache (or see from incognito) - if the website is the same be sure you deployed what intended